# Programmatically populate Gridview with data text fields with edmx

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, entity-framework-4, edmx

I'm struggling with a problem here. 
I have an edm query in c# where I populate 1 (one) grid view control with multiple tables depending on what the user selects. I get it to work and populate the table with all the data.

I need to know what the best possible way is to load the column names with the data for them in the rows. I can't pre-load the grid view with the column names since the data will differ each time. I also want a button field on the grid view with the text displaying as the primary Id for the table.

I have tried just about everything, any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
  using (ITIncidentsEntities dbc = new ITIncidentsEntities()) {

        var Query = (from c in dbc.GeneralIncidents
                     select c);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDate.Text))
        {
            DateTime _date = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text);
            Query = Query.Where(c => c.CreateDate == _date);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtAuthor.Text))
        {
            Query = Query.Where(c => c.Author.Contains(txtAuthor.Text));
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtIncidentFormat.Text))
        {
            Query = Query.Where(c => c.Title == txtIncidentFormat.Text);
        }

        grvResults.DataSource = Query.ToArray();
        grvResults.DataBind();
        grvResults.Columns.Add(new ButtonField { HeaderText = "Print", Text = "??? Datavalue Field" });
   }
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the solution that works for me.

```
grvResults.DataSource = Query.ToArray();
grvResults.Columns.Add(new BoundField { DataField = "ValueID", HeaderText = "General ID" });
grvResults.Columns.Add(new BoundField { DataField = "Value", HeaderText = "General" });
grvResults.DataBind();
```

I will just generate this per selection of the user where appropriate.